# Ionic Framework Login API - Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I made a basic login form and authentification service with the Ionic Framework and I keep running into CORS issues. When I run the app on Google Chrome and try to log in I get this error:
[HTTP preflight response error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFmuQ.jpg)

`Failed to load http://example.com/api.login: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status`

This is the most common error I have been getting, but I also keep getting errors with making OPTIONS requests (even though I am making a POST request but I heard that's what ionic does in the dev browser). I am using a basic REST API with the Slim framework hosted on my GoDaddy server. I did some research and everyone keeps saying I need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` to my .htaccess file.

Here is the `.htaccess` file in my APIs file structure:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /api/

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I checked to make sure that the API is working with Postman and both login and register are working properly. And of course, I am typing in the login information correctly.

Here is my `auth-service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  static readonly LOGIN_URL = 'http://example.com/api/login';
  static readonly REGISTER_URL = 'http://example.com/api/register';
  access: boolean;
  token: string;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.username === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials.");
    } else {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.http.post(AuthServiceProvider.LOGIN_URL, credentials)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe( data => {
          if (data.access_token) {
            this.token = 'Bearer ' + data.access_token;
            this.access = true;
          } else {
            this.access = false;
          }
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
              observer.next(this.access);
          }, 500);

        setTimeout(() => {
              observer.complete();
          }, 1000);


      }, err => console.error(err));
    }
  }
```

And `login.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  loading: Loading;
  userData = { username: '', password: '' };

  constructor(
    public nav: NavController,
    private auth: AuthServiceProvider,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
  ) {}

  public createAccount() {
    this.nav.push('RegisterPage');
  }

  public login() {
    console.log(this.userData);
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.userData).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
      } else {
        this.showError("These credentials do not match our records.");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }

  showError(text) {
    this.loading.dismiss();

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Fail',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

I have tried creating a proxy server in my `ionic.config.json` file and changing the URLs in `auth-service.ts`. No dice.

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "proxies" : [
    {
      "path" : "/api/",
      "proxyUrl" : "http://example.com/api/"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I go about fixing this?

I am using OSX 10.12.6, Ionic 3, and editing in Atom.

Comment: if you are calling your login api from a local host server and also the app runs on a local host it is tend to do the CORSE Issue as NODEJS has it written!   if your target api for back end  is on a different server than you should see the disabling the cores for test purposes though its not recommended! but at-least that way you can move forward!

Comment: if i were you and had backend and app on a same MACHINe! i would have ended up using some free backend to host my login api algorithm or  maybe ngrok help had been taken please see https://ngrok.com/...    CORS errors are so heart breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having similar issue, while building an ionic app with opencart php backend. solved it by adding following `headers` to the route from which i was requesting data.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

I have no experience with slim framework, below example is in plain php, just to give you an example.

example: [image: Cors test]

i would suggest that you remove those `headers` entries from `.htaccess` file, that might create additional issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is common CORS issue. you might want to take help of proxy.conf.json file. In this file you can specify and defer your API calls to pass the CORS issue. But keep in mind, this is useful for Dev environment.

Comment: You can further look into proxy.cong.json configuration files at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md